# How to modify the regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text as below and some words and their meanings are included in the text.I need to get these words using a Javascript regex method. For example, if I give below text than return words should be `Necessity, Lay of the land, and Mumble`.

> Necessity:(noun)the need for something, or something that is needed
> Example: In my work, a computer is a necessity.
>
> Lay of the land: (idiom n. Or v.)the general state or condition of
> affairs under consideration; the facts of a situation Example: We
> asked a few questions to get the lay of the land
>
> Mumble:(verb) to speak quietly or in an unclear way so that the words
> are difficult to understand Example: She mumbled something about
> needing to be home, then left.

I have coded as below but it doesn't work as expected.

```js
let text = `Necessity:(noun)the need for something, or something that is needed
Example: In my work, a computer is a necessity.

Lay of the land: (idiom n. Or v.)the general state or condition of affairs under consideration; the facts of a situation
Example: We asked a few questions to get the lay of the land.

Mumble:(verb) to speak quietly or in an unclear way so that the words are difficult to understand
Example: She mumbled something about needing to be home, then left.
`;

let matches = text.match(/[A-Za-z]+(?=\:\S)/g);

console.log(matches); //['Necessity', 'Mumble']
```

May I know what am I missing? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this version:

```js
let text = `Necessity:(noun)the need for something, or something that is needed
Example: In my work, a computer is a necessity.

Lay of the land: (idiom n. Or v.)the general state or condition of affairs under consideration; the facts of a situation
Example: We asked a few questions to get the lay of the land.

Mumble:(verb) to speak quietly or in an unclear way so that the words are difficult to understand
Example: She mumbled something about needing to be home, then left.
`;

let matches = text.match(/(^|(?<=\n\n))\w+(?: \w+)*(?=:)/g);

console.log(matches);
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern used:

- `(`

  - `^` the start of the string
  - `|` OR
  - `(?<=\n\n)` lookbehind and assert two newlines precede
- `)`
- `\w+` match a word
- `(?: \w+)*` followed by space and another word, zero or more times
- `(?=:)` assert that `:` follows this word or words

Answer (score 3):

You may use this regex:

```bash
/^[A-Za-z]+(?:\s+[A-Za-z]+)*(?=:)/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aMfpsU/1)

**RegEx Breakdown:**

- `^`: Start
- `[A-Za-z]+`: Match 1+ of English letters
- `(?:\s+[A-Za-z]+)*`: Match 1+ whitespaces followed by 1+ of English letters. Repeat this group 0 or more times.
- `(?=:)`: Lookahead to assert that we have `:` at next position

Answer (score 2):

I like my Regex's as short as possible so here's my take.

```js
const text = `Necessity:(noun)the need for something, or something that is needed Example: In my work, a computer is a necessity.

Lay of the land: (idiom n. Or v.)the general state or condition of affairs under consideration; the facts of a situation Example: We asked a few questions to get the lay of the land

Mumble:(verb) to speak quietly or in an unclear way so that the words are difficult to understand Example: She mumbled something about needing to be home, then left.`;

let matches = text.match(/^\S[^:]+/gm);
console.log(matches);
```

Breakdown:

- `^` asserts start of line
- `\S` matches any non-whitespace character.
- `[^:]+` matches all character which isn't `:` one or unlimited times.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as above:

```
let regex_exp = /(^|(?<=\n\n))\w+(?: \w+)*(?=:)/g;
let matches = text.match(regex_exp);
console.warn(matches);
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer looks below answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74741597/7901430 What's different?

Answer (score 0):

In your pattern `[A-Za-z]+(?=\:\S)` you are not matching any spaces in case of multiple words, and you are asserting a colon to the right followed by a non whitespace char using `(?=\:\S)`

If there should be a part with a colon and parenthesis following and using a capture group:

```
^([A-Za-z].*?):\s*\([^()]*\)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `([A-Za-z].*?)` Capture group 1, match a char A-Za-z followed by any char except a newline, as least as possible
- `:\s*` Match a colon and optional whitespace chars
- `\([^()]*\)` Match from `(...)`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z3ISWO/1).

```js
const regex = /^([A-Za-z].*?):\s*\([^()]*\)/gm;
const str = `Necessity:(noun)the need for something, or something that is needed Example: In my work, a computer is a necessity.

Lay of the land: (idiom n. Or v.)the general state or condition of affairs under consideration; the facts of a situation Example: We asked a few questions to get the lay of the land

Mumble:(verb) to speak quietly or in an unclear way so that the words are difficult to understand Example: She mumbled something about needing to be home, then left.`;

const result = Array.from(str.matchAll(regex), m => m[1]);
console.log(result);
```